# A good example of set A such that $(A')\cap (A')'=\emptyset$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I tried to show that $A=\{1/n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is such that $A'=\{0\}$ but $(A')'=\emptyset$ but I can't imagine a set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the same property and obviusly non trivial, like $A=\{(0,1/n):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ or similary, Can you please provide some example and hints for prove it if you consider that necesary?

Comment: Why is $(A')' = \emptyset$?

Comment: It's not. $(A')' = \emptyset$.

Comment: @mathworker21 I made the correction?

Comment: What is the apostrophe symbol?

Comment: $A'$ means the set of all cluster points of $A$.

Comment: Sorry but I think that singular sets has empty derivated set in $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology, because a finite set has only isolated points, can you explain to me my mistake?

Comment: So you just have to find a set with limit points that form a nowhere-dense set?

Comment: ONe issue is your use of similarly. For (non-trivial) example your set will have to be dense about some point a. But this is just to say there is an element of the ball with radius 1/n and center a for arbitrarily small n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way this is possible is if $A^{\prime\prime}$ is empty, since $A^{\prime\prime} \subseteq A^\prime$ for any $A \subseteq \mathbb R^2$. Below let $d$ denote the usual Euclidean metric on $\mathbb R^2$.

- Suppose that $x \in A^{\prime\prime}$, and let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then there is a $y \in A^\prime$ with $0 < d(x,y) < \varepsilon$. Set $\delta = \min \{ d(x,y) , \varepsilon - d(x,y) \} > 0$. Then there is a $z \in A$ with $0 < d(y,z) < \delta$. Note now that $$d(x,z) \leq d(x,y)+d(y,z) < d(x,y) + \delta \leq d(x,y) + (\varepsilon - d(x,y)) = \varepsilon.$$ Also since $d(y,z) < \delta \leq d(x,y)$ it must be that $x \neq z$. Therefore $x \in A^\prime$.

---

The above proof works for any metric space. This set inclusions holds more generally for T<sub>1</sub>-spaces.

- Let $X$ be T<sub>1</sub>, and let $A \subseteq X$. Suppose $x \in A^{\prime\prime}$. Let $U$ be any open neighborhood of $x$. Then there is a $y \in U \cap A^\prime$ with $y \neq x$. Since $X$ is T<sub>1</sub>, it follows that $U \setminus \{ x \}$ is an open neighborhood of $y$. As $y \in A^\prime$ there is a $z \in ( U \setminus \{ x \} ) \cap A$ with $z \neq y$. Clearly $z \in U \cap A$ and $z \neq x$. Therefore $x \in A^\prime$.

Comment: I was thinking in that, but I still without finding the example non-trivial... jajaja

Comment: This also follows from the fact that $A'$ is closed.